# Need aid with the code I wrote (need to understand)

Tags: java

The code below is what I have wrote for my assignment for class.
I have not learned from the instructor yet about the arrays, and
data. I have understood how to use the arrays, but not quite sure
about the data yet.
I have marked where I need help for the code below.
Although I have managed to write it, still not sure if it is optimal.
Could someone help me to better it perhaps?

*I asked previously about finding the mode, and people told me to do it with the
map implementation, I tried to do it, but my brain won't work for it.. any suggestions?

=================================================================================

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class CodeVer2 {


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Double num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, sum, avg;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the first number:");
    num1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the seond number:");
    num2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the third number:");
    num3 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the fourth number:");
    num4 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the fifth number:");
    num5 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    keyboard.close();

    double[] num = new double[5]; // array named num is declared with 5 variables
    num[0] = num1;
    num[1] = num2;
    num[2] = num3;
    num[3] = num4;
    num[4] = num5;
    Arrays.sort(num);

    double[] data = {num1, num2, num3, num4, num5}; // I need help from here,
    int mode = 0;
    int[] index = new int[999];
    int maximum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        index[(int) data[i]]++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < index.length; i++){
        if(maximum < index[i]){
            maximum = index[i];
            mode = i;
        }
    }                                               // to here.

    sum = num[0] + num[1] + num[2] + num[3] + num[4];
    avg = sum/5;

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Sum:" + sum);
    System.out.println("Avg:" + avg);
    System.out.println("Max:" + num[4]);
    System.out.println("Min:" + num[0]);
    System.out.println("Median:" + num[2]);
    System.out.println("Mode:" + mode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Incorrect code, try to develop more concisely

Comment: It works fine. Is there any thing wrong with the grammar?

Comment: This will work for what you want to do. Especially if you have not covered arrays yet, people's suggestion about using a "map" (e.g. HashMap) would probably be too advanced...although much better suited to the problem. Besides error checking, nothing wrong with your code though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all `double[]` does is set up an array that can contain 0 or more numbers. Think of it like a sheet of paper with a row of boxes on it. You can't add more boxes or take them away but you can write a different number in each box.

```
double[] data = {num1, num2, num3, num4, num5}; // I need help from here,
```

This creates a row of boxes, and writes the numbers in the { } into the row. It automatically creates the row to be the right size to hold the things in the brackets.

```
int mode = 0;
int[] index = new int[999];
int maximum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

This creates a new list of boxes, these ones can each hold an integer and there are 999 of them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    index[(int) data[i]]++;
}
```

This loops through your data. data[i] says "use the value in the box numbered i, counting from the start of the boxes with the first box being 0".

It converts that double value to an integer and then looks up the box corresponding to that integer. It adds one to the value at that position. Note that there is a flaw in the algorithm here, if someone puts in a number over 999 then you won't have enough boxes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < index.length; i++){
    if(maximum < index[i]){
        maximum = index[i];
        mode = i;
    }
}
```

Now this loops through every box in the index array. Since earlier values are over-ridden and since you never actually calculate the maximum it actually just gives you the value in box 999 of the array and sets mode to 999. That doesn't sound very useful...

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the kind of explanation that I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

first of all I rewrote your code to make it easier to read.
What is missing is: what does this "mode" mean. I couldn't derive it from your code.

The code below is not perfect. A lot of error handling and boundary checking is missing. I leave that as an exercise for you.

So, try to understand what my code does. Think about the meaning of "mode" and how to calculate it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class CodeVer2 {

    static final String CARDNAME[] = { "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth" };
    static final int NUM_ITEMS = 5;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double num[], sum, avg, max, min;
    double mode = 0.0;  // don't know what this is
    int i;

    num = new double[NUM_ITEMS];
    sum = 0;
    max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ITEMS; ++i) {
         System.out.println("Enter the " + CARDNAME[i] + " number:");
         num[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
         sum += num[i];
         if (max < num[i]) max = num[i];
         if (min > num[i]) min = num[i];
    }
    avg = sum / NUM_ITEMS;
    Arrays.sort(num);

    keyboard.close();

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Sum:" + sum);
    System.out.println("Avg:" + avg);
    System.out.println("Max:" + max);
    System.out.println("Min:" + min);
    System.out.println("Median:" + num[NUM_ITEMS/2]);
    System.out.println("Mode:" + mode);
    }
}
```

Comment: While you are right - he was asking for understanding, not the solution. Particularly if (as seems likely) his is a homework quesiton...

Comment: the mode is the most frequent user-input value. I have managed to make that happen on the code I wrote up there.
I wasn't asking for a solution.
It was rather like "Mine works well. But could there be any way to better my code?"

Comment: Mode is the number that occurs the most number of times, hence the OP's second iteration through `index` and the `maximum` variable.

Comment: Well, I'm in a good mood :-) So I thought it would be a nice idea to show an elegant, though not perfect (as I already pointed out, solution. I learned a lot about programming languages by reading (well written) code. And my little present does leave some (home)work to do. At least the asking person was honest about the fact that this is homework.

Comment: I mean. I finished the homework, just needed some explanations on my code. Because the median and mode part was not covered in class, and were extra credit parts to the coding assignment. I will look to your codes and try to translate them. Thanks for writing!

Comment: OK, I understand mode now. So use a HashMap, indexed by `new Double(num[i])` and count. Afterwards you iterate over the HashMap using the key() and iterator() methods. I still leave this as an exercise. Read the Java documentation on the Class and methods I mentioned. The original code is severely broken. It doesn't distinguish between 9.5 and 9.7 and it throws an exception on negative or large values.